# G++ makes smaller binary than GCC after C++ compatibility changes, but slightly larger than the prior binary?

Tags: c++, c, g++, compiler-optimization

I made some changes to a C codebase so that it could compile under G++.  Seems to be working, with some annoyances and the hack of `-fpermissive -fshort-wchar`.

Out of curiosity I compared the stripped `-O2` size of the GCC-built executable before my changes, and the G++-built executable after my changes.  The "after" was 32 bytes larger (on a 500K-ish binary).  I was pleasantly surprised it was so close, but idly wondered why if the optimizer is *that* consistent it wouldn't be 100% consistent?  But maybe something about adding that [overload for strchr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906150/minimally-invasive-change-for-strchr-on-unsigned-char-in-c-from-a-c-codebase) caused it.

Not important enough to me to worry about.  But then I decided to a C build with GCC taking my C++ compatibility changes into account.  That stripped `-O2` executable was *4096 bytes bigger* than the C build prior to my changes.

Does anyone have intuition on why these three sizes would happen this way, and why it would be such a "round" number?  The C++ changes were basically all things that should be optimized out, whether in C or C++.  Basically:

- introduction of opaque typing so that functions previously defined in the interface as taking void* would name-mangle consistently.  introduced some cast assignments to locals via macro of the opaque type to a local of the proper internal type
- elimination of a few instances of old-style C function header definition
- modification of linkage to "extern" for some global constants that hadn't specified linkage before, temporarily tolerating [keeping the assignments in the headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908376/extern-const-linkage-specification-being-seemingly-ignored-by-g) but hoping to argue against that
- changing some signed chars to unsigned chars, and some unsigned longs to unsigned int (but never vice versa)

If anyone has a good intuition for this optimization case, then it would save me the time of backing out each set of related changes individually to see how they affect the size...!

Comment: All these size differences are so small, I would just totally ignore them. It's extremely unlikely that they suggest anything interesting, broken, or relevant. It could even just be linker order causing different amounts of padding.

Comment: An ELF executable has a lot of things inside, some of them are rounded up to a size multiple of a given power of 2. Probably that's why the 4096. You should check the output of `objdump -x <exe-file>` on both programs and compare bit by bit.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'd agree under most circumstances, and would like to ignore them, but I'm trying to slipstream some changes into a C project that is very size-conscious and not necessarily friendly to bowing to modifications that serve those interested in building with a C++ compiler.  So it's good to at least have answers.  If it's an ELF chunk-size and could be explained in the noise, then being able to show that will be handy...

Comment: Slight correction to rodrigo's comment.  The ELF can be organized into blocks to improve swapping of code pages. 4096 is a common block size.  It doesn't require a power of two for the entire executable. Whether this tactic is used is entirely compiler dependent. It can mean that if a 32-byte size addition takes you over a block boundary, you pay for the whole block.

Comment: Another possibility is that there are certain constructs that both a C compiler and a C++ compiler will accept, but have (sometimes subtly) different semantics, which will lead the compiler to either generate slightly different code and/or the optimizer to make some different decisions about rearranging stuff. It might be useful to compare generated assembly output to see what differences there are...

Comment: @twalberg: These differences between C and C++ are few, subtle and generally quite artificial. I'd bet more on something like exception stack frames, RTTI, or struct constructors/destructors/copy-operators. Or maybe simply different optimization choices due to different expected usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember: a C++ program is not intrinsically larger than a C program.  The compilation may take more time, but there's nothing that inherently makes a C++ program larger.

And actually...due to the stricter formalisms and wiggle room left for [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), a C++ compiler may be able to make more optimizations on a C codebase than a C compiler could.

The differences you *(a.k.a. me)* are describing are small.  And as @rodrigo and @MelNicholson point out, even a tiny difference may be exaggerated by block size rounding.  A single byte of actual difference could thus lead to 4096 bytes of file size difference.

It might be interesting to grab a bunch of regression tests for a C compiler, build it as C vs. C++ and see if there are any notable differences in executable size, then look for patterns in what causes those differences.  If you *(a.k.a. me)* have the time.  It might provide data to feed back into places the compilers could be improved.  But there's basically nothing at all to be learned from a single-instance difference of this size on a 500K executable.